# I am trying to create a configuration script in perl that will make changes in two parameters , I need to know the ideal construct

Tags: perl, command-line, configuration, creation

So far I am using the following construct

```
configure.pl <$ARGV[0]> <$ARGV[1]>
```

each given argument can be

```
+n = to increase the current service by n 
-n = to decrease the existing services by n
n = to create n number of services ( irrespective of the number of existing services )
```

I have a doubt whether this is the correct construct , I also have problems in fixing what should i have for nochange (ie existing services should continue ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line interface you propose is perfectly fine as long as it's documented.

The [GNU coding standards recommend providing long options](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces). It is easy to have those in addition to the short options with [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](http://p3rl.org/Getopt%3a%3aLong%3a%3aDescriptive).

```
--inc=n
+n
        to increase the current service by n

--dec=n
-n
        to decrease the existing services by n

--abs=n
n
        to create n number of services (irrespective of the number of existing services)

--no-op
        no change in operation, existing services continue as is
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Since I have two such services . I will use   $ARGV[0] as input for first service and <$ARGV1> as input for second service . So does that require 4 command line arguments If i were to put "--inc n" , "--dec n" etc

Comment: No, that would be cumbersome; so I have edited the answer to add equal signs between parameter name and value, the Getopt::Long library will split them apart automatically.

Comment: I got it now , thanks a lot . I feel sorry that I couldn't rate this answer as useful since I don't have enough reputation ..